# How to list Contianer List using port wise

Tags: linux, docker, command, port, devops

I want to list some port wise containers running on the server.
For Ex. I want to list all containers running on the 8080 or 443 port. So any command for that list only container are running the selected port.

Answer (score 0):

You can list docker containers filtered by port with command `docker ps --filter "publish=<port>"` or `docker ps --filter "expose=<port>"` depending whether you want to see published/exposed ports.

`<port>` format from command examples above could be like `<startport-endport>/[<proto>]` or `<port>[/<proto>]`

For more details see https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/ps/#filtering